# How do I POST a url to a non-SSL server from a https

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl

I have a server running that's controlling my TV, and I want to be able to push links to it using a bookmarklet. Right now, everything works perfectly fine unless I'm trying to push a https link to it.

Here's the bookmarklet code:

```
(function(){

    // the minimum version of jQuery we want
    var v = "1.3.2";

    // check prior inclusion and version
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < v) {
        var done = false;
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + v + "/jquery.min.js";
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
                done = true;
                initMyBookmarklet();
            }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    } else {
        initMyBookmarklet();
    }

    function initMyBookmarklet() {
        (window.myBookmarklet = function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://192.168.1.2:4567",
                type: "GET",
                data: {url: "http://" + document.URL.replace(/https?:\/\//i, "")},
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });
        })();
    }

})();
```

The issue is that `http://192.168.1.2:4567` is not a https url, so when trying to execute this bookmarklet on any https website, I get the following error:

`[blocked] The page at 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-rM3FRlt9o' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://192.168.1.2:4567/?callback=jsonp1406774222812&_=1406774936255&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DS-rM3FRlt9o': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.`

Is there any way to get around this using javascript?

Comment: An alternative: add a certificate to the server that's controlling your TV so the page can be served over HTTPS.

Comment: @jww Any idea how to do that with Sinatra?